# Do sounds waves created by human speech penetrate the body?

Tags: waves, vibrations

I'm not sure if this question is quite fitting. But does sound penetrate the body in a "usable" way?
By that I mean if we were to somehow implant a small microphone inside the body (not too deep) would it be able to pick up sounds that could be listened to?

I'm fairly sure since sound is just vibrations it could pick up what you were saying at least as it would pick up the vibrations of your vocal chords, but would the recording be intelligible? Would it be able to pick up say someone talking to you as well?

Comment: I assume you have heard of [sonograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound)?

Comment: Are you only interested in the frequency range occupied by human speech? From the title it sounds like 'ultrasound' would be the appropriate response, however the body of your text focuses on using a person's speech.

Comment: @LioElbammalf very good point I didn't consider ultrasound so the title is very misleading. I meant regularly occurring sounds such as speech and any other ambient sound.

Comment: If you visit an airport for example, and watch the aircraft taxi in, you can see the apron turnaround staff communicate with the flight crew in the cockpit using microphones around their throats / voicebox, and also allowing them to talk to other staff, such as fuel loaders, in the ordinary way.